# Value of auth.provider for Phone Authentication & Facebook in Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables), the values for all providers are given except for Phone Authentication. I want to verify in my database if a user has authenticated with both Phone Authentication and Facebook. Writing a rule as `auth.provider === 'facebook'` works, but `auth.provider === 'phone'` doesn't. Logically, if the first one worked then the second one shouldn't work, but what if I say that I always sign in with Phone credentials and linked Facebook credentials with the Phone credentials the first time? In a nutshell:

1. Is there a value of `auth.provider` for Phone Authentication? If yes, what is it?
2. Is there a way to check if the user has both Facebook and Phone as providers in my database? I don't care if the user signs in with either of them. The only thing I want is that the user should have linked his Facebook credentials to the Phone.
3. Assuming that `auth.provider` only gives the value of the provider used to sign in, why is `auth.provider === 'facebook'` working when I never sign in a user with Facebook and only link it with Phone credentials?

**Update:**

1. With some trial and error, it seems that if Phone authentication is the only method used, then `auth.provider` is actually `anonymous`, **not** `phone`.
2. Also, based on [bojeil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5081766/bojeil) answer, `auth.token.firebase.identities["phone"] !=null` turns out to be `true`. Point to be noted is that this is **not** documented in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken). Quoting from the documentation:

> **firebase.identities**:  Dictionary of all the identities that are associated with this user's account. The keys of the dictionary can be any of the following: **email**, **google.com**, **facebook.com**, **github.com**, **twitter.com**.

No mention of **phone** here either. The last day the page was updated was *May 17, 2017*. One can only imagine the level of shoddiness in the documentation considering the Firebase SDK for Javascript (v4.0.0), which includes support for Phone authentication, was released on that very day (see [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)).

Comment: Hey Mayank try using `auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider === 'phone' `instead of `auth.provider`.  I will report `auth.provider` not being populated and the docs regarding token data not being up to date.

Comment: `auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider === 'phone'` works. Also, `auth.provider === 'anonymous'` works. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: I have filed a bug report regarding this. Using auth.provider === 'anonymous' is definitely incorrect. An actual anonymous user will pass that check. You should use the former check until the latter is fixed.

Comment: @bojeil Can you post the link of the bug report? This is a case of security breach and must be fixed as soon as possible. As for myself, I'm using the rule as described in my answer. Neither it allows an anonymous user nor the rule shall (likely) break when they fix it.

Comment: This is a bug. It is not a security breach. You can use the solution I posted for detecting a signed in phone user via `auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider`. The bug report is internal. There is no external link to it. Feel free to file a report with Firebase Support too. I will post any update from Firebase once I get it.

Comment: Bugs become security breaches if used intelligently. If I had used `auth.provider === anonymous` to detect authentication through phone, I'd also have had to allow actual `anonymous` users along with the `phone` users. Using `auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider` is a solution to mitigate the issue. However, devs who use the former approach to "ensure" phone authentication will ultimately risk the security of data. So, I consider this a security breach. You could argue, though, that the onus is on the dev and not the Firebase team, because he used a buggy undocumented rule.

Comment: If you used `auth.provider === anonymous` then that is clearly an error on your end. You don't build a solution based on a bug. There is nothing Firebase can do to fix that. I already suggested a correct and safe workaround which you keep ignoring in favor of your bug based solution.

Comment: I'm not ignoring anything. See my answer.

Comment: This should be fixed now. The docs have also been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exploiting some of the *undocumented* features (read the question for reason), one can write the following rule to accomplish the task:

`$uid === auth.uid && auth.token.firebase.identities['phone']!=null && auth.token.firebase.identities['facebook.com']!=null`

**Update:** This solution works perfectly as per updated documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For database/storage rules, `auth.provider` will only show the provider used to authenticate the user and generate the token (not the one used for linking). This can be either `phone` or `facebook`. It can't be both. You only authenticate with one at a time. Firebase doesn't support multi factor auth.

That said, if you want to check the user has both providers linked, the right way to do is to check: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken
specifically, `auth.token.firebase.identities`
You can check if the following exist:
`auth.token.firebase.identities["facebook.com"]`
`auth.token.firebase.identities["phone"]`